# How to determine which pattern in a file matched with grep?

Tags: grep, procmail

I use procmail to do extensive sorting on my inbox.  My next to last recipe matches the incoming From: to a (very) long white/gold list of historically good email addresses, and patterns of email addresses.  The recipe is:

```
# Anything on the goldlist goes straight to inbox
:0
* ? formail -zxFrom: -zxReply-To | fgrep -i -f $HOME/Mail/goldlist
{
  LOG="RULE Gold: "
  :0:
  $DEFAULT
}
```

The final recipe puts everything left in a suspect folder to be examined as probable spam. Goldlist is currenltty 7384 lines long (yikes...).  Every once in a while, I get a piece of spam that has slipped through and I want to fix the failing pattern.  I thought I read a while ago about a special flag in grep that helped show the matching patterns, but I can't find that again.  Is there a way to use grep that shows the pattern from a file that matched the scanned text?  Or another similar tool that would answer the question short of writing a script to scan pattern by pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep -o will output only the matched text (as opposed to the whole line).  That may help.  Otherwise, I think you'll need to write a wrapper script to try one pattern at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help you or not.  There is a "-o" parameter to output only the matching expression.

From the man page:

> ```
>    -o, --only-matching
>           Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
> ```